# Perform Addition/operation on data from Firebase Firestore Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving data from Firestore where each document stores 2 fields, one is a date and the other is seconds. I want to group the data as such that the seconds are added up for each date.

For example, I have 3 documents and 2 with the same dates but different seconds:

```
date: 21-04-2019, 
timeTrained: 86
```

2nd document:

```
date: 21-04-2019, 
timeTrained: 24
```

3rd document:

```
date: 20-04-2019, 
timeTrained: 120
```

So I would like to add the`timeTrained` in the first and second documents as they have the same date, I will have many documents like this in my Firestore collection so I need this to be dynamic instead of hard coded.

Picture below to provide snapshot of data stored in Firestore.

[image: image of firestore db]

Comment: To understand better, you want to count the value of all `timeTrained` properties where the `date` is for example `21-04-2019`, right?

Comment: yes as later on this will be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference userExercisesRef = rootRef.collection("userExercises");
Query query = userExercisesRef.whereEqualTo("date", "21-04-2019");
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            long count = 0;
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                long timeTrained = document.getLong("timeTrained");
                count = count + timeTrained;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(count));
        }
    }
});
```

According to your provided data, for `21-04-2019` the result in your logcat will be:

```
110
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that. So if I wanted to update the timeTrained value I would just pass it the count variable right?

Comment: No, if you want to update that `timeTrained` value, you need to know the exact path to that property. Firebase does not have the concept of SQL's update queries.

So in your case you'll need to first read the nodes you want to update, then loop over them, and then update them either one by one or with one big multi-location update statement.